# form tabcontrol subform runtime error 468: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ms-access, tabs, ms-access-2007, vba, subform

I am developing a search form / report builder in Access 2007 called `frmSearch`. The existing search form works well, showing its results in a subform of a tabcontrol. Then I can click a button to show a report of all tests, which works fine. I want to modify the code to show a report for a single `fldTestsID`, but am stuck with the Form/Subform/Control path syntax.

There are two tabs: `tabResultsTabular` shows a subform `frmResultsTabular` as a query-like list of row. `tabResultsRecord` shows a subform `frmResultsRecords`, showing a single record. The report is `rpt_TestDatasetExposureEffects`. The report's underlying query is `q_TestDatasetExposureEffect` containing a field called `fldTestsID`.

So, the path is `frmSearch` to `tabResultsRecord` containing button `cmdQAReportResults` to `frmResultsRecords` to `fldTestsID`.

I see that that are other posts for the same error, but did not get them to work. The Access 2007 docs on DoCmd.OpenReport do not mention this specific instance.

Here is the code of the `cmdQAReportResults` click event including the options I have tried. It fails on the line `strRptWhere =`.  The `DoCmd.OpenReport` syntax is working based on the [Access 2007 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

```
Private Sub cmdQAReportResults_Click()
    doQAReport
End Sub

Private Sub doQAReport()
'On Error GoTo Err_doQAReport 'comment during debugging
   Dim stDocName As String ' report name
'   Dim strRptSQL As String ' report SQL String
   Dim strRptWhere As String ' report WHERE clause

   stDocName = "rpt_TestDatasetExposureEffects"
    'Override the recordsource to match the current record TestsID
'   strRptSQL = "SELECT * FROM q_TestDatasetExposureEffects WHERE fldTestsID = " & fldTestsID
'   DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview
    strRptWhere = "0 = 0"
    strRptWhere = "fldTestsID = " & Me.Form![tabResultsRecord].fldTestsID.Value 'error 468
'    other attempts follow
'    strRptWhere = "fldTestsID = " & Forms("frmSearch").Controls("tabResultsRecord").Form.Controls("frmResultsRecords").Form.Controls("fldTestsID").Value
'    strRptWhere = "fldTestsID = " & Me.Form.fldTestsID 'error 2465

   DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , strRptWhere
'    Reports("rpt_TestDatasetExposureEffects").RecordSource = strRptSQL


Exit_doQAReport:
    Exit Sub

Err_doQAReport:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_doQAReport

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
Forms(<Parent Form>).<control container for subform>.form.<control>
```

In your case this might be:

```
Forms("frmSearch").frmResultsRecords.Form.fldTestsID
```

frmResultsRecords is the name of the subform, but is it also the name of the subform's container?

If not, replace it with the name of the control on the main form containing the subform.

Comment: I am getting the same error 438 on this line. 
    `strRptWhere = "fldTestsID = " & Forms("frmSearch").Form.frmResultsRecords.fldTestsID` 

When I click on the subform's border and F4 to show properties, it says the item name is frmResultsRecords. The form name in the object viewer is also frmResultsRecords.

Comment: Is the name of the control fldTestID or is that the name of the field?

Comment: I just noticed that in my example I put `Form` in the wrong place, it did not match the syntax above it, so I have fixed that. Try changing that.

Comment: Yes, That worked! Thank you. The text field containing the key value is fldTestsID.